# How to understand which runicast message you have succesfully transmitted in Contiki (Rime)?

Tags: iot, contiki

After that I send different runicast messages with the function `runicast_send`,  how can I understand which message was acknowledged when the callback `sent_runicast` is triggered?

The [runicast.h](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/net/rime/runicast.h) file states:

> The runicast primitive adds two packet attributes: the single-hop
>    packet type and the single-hop packet ID.  The runicast primitive
>    uses the packet ID attribute as a sequence number for matching
>    acknowledgement packets to the corresponding data packets.

but I didn't understand how to do it in practice. Can somebody provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to look at the field `sndnxt` of `struct runicast_conn *c` before you send the packet, and then compare that value of the `packetbuf_attr(PACKETBUF_ATTR_PACKET_ID)` in the "sent" callback of your code.

However note that by default the runicast packet ID is just 2 bits long. Enough to demultiplex the ACK in most cases, but may be insufficient for your purposes. (The packet ID size in bits can be changed by redefining `RUNICAST_PACKET_ID_BITS`.)

Also Rime is obsolete. Don't use it in your code, especially production code unless you know what you're doing. `runicast` was never one of the highlights of Rime, I doubt there are no better alternatives (e.g. the uIPv6 stack) for what you want to do.